# mod_wsgi overriding virtual hosts on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, fedora, django, mod-wsgi

I have a working Django app hosted on my linode (Fedora 15), and I'm attempting to host a php-based site there as well. I'm using name-based virtual hosts to redirect requests based on the host name, but for some reason, every request is going to the Django app. I'm thinking perhaps mod_wsgi is overriding some defaults? Or maybe a syntax error with my virtual hosts (I've tried DocumentRoot with and without quotes)? Here are the relevant parts of my httpd config file:

```
Name VirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName pollvaultr.com
ServerAlias www.pollvaultr.com

WSGIDaemonProcess pollvaultr.com user=apache group=apache
WSGIProcessGroup pollvaultr.com

WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/html/PollVaultr/wsgi.py"

Alias /static/ "/var/www/html/static/"

<Directory "/var/www/html/static">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/PollVaultr">
    <Files "wsgi.py">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/catfacts/"
    ServerName lexiross.com
    ServerAlias www.lexiross.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my wsgi.py script:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/PollVaultr')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PollVaultr.settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Running `httpd -e DEBUG` does not reveal any bugs. Here is the tail of my error_log file:

```
[Fri Feb 24 20:36:42 2012] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=5893): Create interpreter 'lexiross.com|'.
[Fri Feb 24 20:36:42 2012] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=5893): Adding '/var/www/html/' to path.
[Fri Feb 24 20:36:42 2012] [info] [client 140.247.248.217] mod_wsgi (pid=5893, process='', application='lexiross.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/html/PollVaultr/wsgi.py'.
```

Any ideas what could be going on? mod_wsgi definitely shouldn't be dealing with requests made to lexiross.com - why won't those requests head to the alternate document root? I should also mention that this is my first time doing sysadmin work, so I'm very new at this! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not setup the second virtual host properly, or not being found, then Apache will fallback to sending requests to first virtual host it found in configuration.

Are the virtual hosts in same file, different files? If in different files and in sites-available directory, did you actually enable the second site so linked into sites-enabled?

Try adding a syntax error into second virtual host to make sure file is being read.

Also fix your "NameVirtualHost" directive in example, unless that is your problem. Shouldn't have a space in it.

Comment: All my vhosts are in httpd.conf. I'm using Fedora and it looks like sites-available isn't on Fedora as far as I can tell. I haven't been able to find an equivalent. Update: I changed around my file system so I have /var/www/pollvaultr.com/html, /var/www/lexiross.com/html, and /var/www/catfacts.lexiross.com/html as the three documentroots. Now both sites are down, not sure why... Thanks for your help, by the way!

Comment: You didn't fix 'Name VirtualHost *:80' in the example. Is that a mistake in the example or your files?

Comment: Ah, that was just a mistake in the example, not the actual files. Anyway, I got it working now - was just a matter of rearranging the filesystem. Thanks!

Comment: It's only 7 years later but rearranging how @LBR?